# htaccess https too many redirects works not on specific hosting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I want to force redirect HTTP to HTTPS via htaccess. Of course I looked for a tons of solutions here, but nothing helps. On other hosting this solution works but not here.

If I try it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It will redirect to HTTPs, but then it says the page is not working, TOO many redirects.

But I have nothing more in my htaccess, so why too many redirects?

Another solution that works not:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !on  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

Here is the dump of `$_SERVER`:

**HTTP:**

```
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN:  0
SCRIPT_NAME:    /test2.php
REQUEST_URI:    /test2.php
QUERY_STRING:   
REQUEST_METHOD: GET
SERVER_PROTOCOL:    HTTP/1.0
GATEWAY_INTERFACE:  CGI/1.1
REDIRECT_URL:   /test2.php
REMOTE_PORT:    50086
SCRIPT_FILENAME:    /hosting/www/.../test2.php
SERVER_ADMIN:   admin@...
REQUEST_SCHEME: http
DOCUMENT_ROOT:  /hosting/www/example.com/
REMOTE_ADDR:    178.41.4.145
SERVER_PORT:    80
SERVER_ADDR:    178.238.37.248
SERVER_NAME:    www.example.com
SERVER_SOFTWARE:    Apache
SERVER_SIGNATURE:   
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:   sk,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,cs;q=0.6
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:   gzip, deflate
HTTP_ACCEPT:    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
HTTP_USER_AGENT:    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36 Edg/98.0.1108.50
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS: 1
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: max-age=0
HTTP_CONNECTION:    close
HTTP_HOST:  www.example.com
HTTP_AUTHORIZATION: 
BACKEND_NAME:   httpd1
HOSTNAME:   lucy.onebit.cz
UNIQUE_ID:  Yg_Luo5QXSFkFIZSmZji5AAAAMk
REDIRECT_STATUS:    200
REDIRECT_BACKEND_NAME:  httpd1
REDIRECT_HOSTNAME:  lucy.onebit.cz
REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID: Yg_Luo5QXSFkFIZSmZji5AAAAMk
PHP_SELF:   /test2.php
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT: 1645202362.2178
REQUEST_TIME:   1645202362
URL:    /test2.php
STATUS: 200
```

And **HTTPS**:

```
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN:  0
SCRIPT_NAME:    /test2.php
REQUEST_URI:    /test2.php
QUERY_STRING:   
REQUEST_METHOD: GET
SERVER_PROTOCOL:    HTTP/1.0
GATEWAY_INTERFACE:  CGI/1.1
REDIRECT_URL:   /test2.php
REMOTE_PORT:    51668
SCRIPT_FILENAME:    /hosting/www/example.com/www/test2.php
SERVER_ADMIN:   admin@...
REQUEST_SCHEME: http
DOCUMENT_ROOT:  /hosting/www/example.com/
REMOTE_ADDR:    178.41.4.145
SERVER_PORT:    443
SERVER_ADDR:    178.238.37.248
SERVER_NAME:    www.example.com
SERVER_SOFTWARE:    Apache
SERVER_SIGNATURE:   
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:   sk,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,cs;q=0.6
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:   gzip, deflate, br
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST:    document
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER:    ?1
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE:    navigate
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE:    none
HTTP_ACCEPT:    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
HTTP_USER_AGENT:    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36 Edg/98.0.1108.50
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS: 1
HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM:    "Windows"
HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE:  ?0
HTTP_SEC_CH_UA: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Microsoft Edge";v="98"
HTTP_CONNECTION:    close
HTTP_HOST:  www.example.com
HTTP_AUTHORIZATION: 
BACKEND_NAME:   httpd1
HOSTNAME:   lucy.onebit.cz
HTTPS:  on
force_response_1_0: 1
downgrade_1_0:  1
ssl_unclean_shutdown:   1
nokeepalive:    1
Front_End_Https:    on
UNIQUE_ID:  Yg_L4xNbf-I51ics4Sn1UQAAAdM
REDIRECT_STATUS:    200
REDIRECT_BACKEND_NAME:  httpd1
REDIRECT_HOSTNAME:  lucy.onebit.cz
REDIRECT_HTTPS: on
REDIRECT_force_response_1_0:    1
REDIRECT_downgrade_1_0: 1
REDIRECT_ssl_unclean_shutdown:  1
REDIRECT_nokeepalive:   1
REDIRECT_Front_End_Https:   on
REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID: Yg_L4xNbf-I51ics4Sn1UQAAAdM
PHP_SELF:   /test2.php
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT: 1645202403.7653
REQUEST_TIME:   1645202403
HTTP_FRONT_END_HTTPS:   on
URL:    /test2.php
STATUS: 200
```

Comment: What's your Apache version?

Comment: Don't know it is not my hosting, can't access the info. But I think, the problem is with Mod rewrite disabled. I will check with the guy who owns the hosting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I think, the problem is with Mod rewrite disabled.

If mod_rewrite was disabled (and `.htaccess` overrides are enabled) then you'd get a 500 Internal Server Error, not a redirect loop.

You'll get a redirect loop if another service is managing the SSL connection with the client (eg. front-end proxy, load balancer, CDN, etc.) and your application server is connecting via insecure HTTP to this other service. (Not uncommon.)

Check the HTTP request headers reaching your application server, do you see an `X-Forwarded-Proto` header? This would indicate the application server is behind a front-end proxy that manages the SSL connection. In which case, you could do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

NB: Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

However, this could also be host-specific. *Some* shared hosts set an `HTTPS` *environment* variable (not to be confused with the `HTTPS` Apache *server* variable as used in your first example), so you could also try something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

---

**UPDATE:** Based on the output from the PHP `$_SERVER` superglobal, try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Reasoning behind this... there is no `HTTPS` array index at all when requesting over HTTP and it is set to `on` when requesting over HTTPS. This must be an environment variable (set by the host), not an Apache *server* variable, since a server variable would always be set.

*Aside:* The two *conditions* in the rules above (ie. `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http` and `%{ENV:HTTPS} =off`) would simply fail (since neither of these are set) and the rule would do nothing.

NB: You must test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect and ensure the browser cache is clear before testing.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but nothing from that works. i also tried to check if mod_rewrite is enabled, but when I do print_r(apache_get_modules()) I;ve got Error 500 and no result from the server.

Comment: @Darksymphony `apache_get_modules()` is only available if PHP is installed as an Apache module. But, as I stated at the top of my answer, mod_rewrite must be enabled, otherwise you wouldn't get a redirect-loop in the first place. If you are using PHP then dump the contents of the `$_SERVER` superglobal (when requesting HTTP and again over HTTPS) and add this to your question - this will give clues as to how to resolve this.

Comment: @Darksymphony "but nothing from that works" - To clarify, neither of these two rules resulted in a redirect-loop (as you had initially)?

Comment: yes, you are right, the redirect is working, because I see HTTP is redirected to HTTPS in browser, but then the page works not due to TOO MANY REDIRECTS issue. I updated my question with $_SERVER dump for HTTP and HTTPS

Comment: I see there HOSTNAME is different from SERVER_NAME, not sure if that may cause problems

Comment: @Darksymphony I'm not sure that I understand your previous comment... "the redirect is working" and you are not getting a redirect-loop and the page works?!

Comment: the redirect works if I put to the URl http://www.example.com, it will change to https, but the page is not loaded, just a message Page is not working, too many redirects.

Comment: @Darksymphony I've updated my answer with a solution based on the output from your `$_SERVER` array. However, "too many redirects" - the two rules I posted should not have resulted in a redirect loop (I would have said that was impossible with the given information) - so maybe something else was triggering this? Or a caching issue? What is the nature of the redirect-loop - check the network traffic in the browser devtools.

Comment: WELL, if I used the solution from your last update, firstly with 302, now it is working! I don't understand what happened, because before I used it in incognito mode to avoid caching. Now I put it back to 301 and still works. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Darksymphony That's great! :) Were you using a "new" incognito session each time? Incognito mode still uses caching; it's just a separate cache from the "normal" mode. I've updated my answer with a bit more reasoning/explanation.

Comment: Maybe I used the same incognito window. But seems the main core issue was to use ENV:HTTPS as you suggested, because just HTTPS was not working on this hosting, it is a first time I met such an issue, on all past hostings my solution normally worked. At least I learned something new :)