# PDF file is insecure in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

This may be a stupid question and have an obvious answer.
My WordPress is serving pages over HTTPS/SSL correctly without any issues (no mixed contenting warding...etc)

However, I couldn't figure out why the page is insecure when I type this URL (w/o `https://www.`) in my browser:

```
example.com/wp-content/uploads/note.pdf
```

But this URL (with https://www.) is secure:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/note.pdf
```

Comment: There is no way to answer this without knowing what rewrite rules you have.  Please add any relevant sections from your `.htaccess` to the question.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller This question was actually resolved with the code in my answer on the linked "duplicate" question - see the comments on the answer below. (But yes, this question is really missing half the detail as it seems they had previously tried to implement an HTTP to HTTPS redirect but got a redirect loop when doing so.)

Comment: Excellent use of your gold-badge powers @MrWhite

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup redirection of non-secure URL addresses to their secure versions, this can be made by adding the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that. I got ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

Comment: Redirecting to the secure URLs can be made by variety of configuration directives, not all of them are correct, are you sure that this listed configuration above is causing the error reported?

Comment: @user1177437 See the following question if you are getting a redirect loop... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71164097/htaccess-https-too-many-redirects-works-not-on-specific-hosting

Comment: @MrWhite  Thanks for the link. This code works:
"RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]"

Comment: @user1177437 That's great. Please upvote answers you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)